# Как выполнить анализ текстовых логов на python?

Tags: python, логирование, текст

Необходимо выполнить анализ текстовых логов, в которых есть информация о логинах и логаутах пользователей системы.

Записи о логине и логауте выглядят следующим образом:

> 10:08:54 AM Login successful from user Sergey Pavlov id_session=2710 
> 10:35:33 PM Closing session (user $escalation$, reserved) id_session=2710 reason=1,20

По тэгу «Login successful» понимаем, что пользователь Sergey Pavlov зашёл, и получаем номер сессии `id_session=2710` . Далее ищем по тэгу «Closing session» этот же номер сессии – понимаем, что пользователь вышел.

Мне нужно выяснить сколько времени он был активен сравнив номер сессии. Грубо говоря мне нужно достать id, ФИО и время.

Comment: Ну, перебираете строки из файла, парсите из него дату, логин/логаут и id сессии. После сопоставляете. Например, заполняйте словарь как ид. сессии (или по user) к списку из логина/логаута с датой. Парсить можно регуляркой или поиском по конкретным словам, а после разделением по пробелам, но регуляркой будет проще

Comment: я бы делал это используя модуль Pandas - это упростит многие шаги, но потребует время на изучение базового функционала Pandas...

Answer (score 1):

Мыслишь правильно.
Используй регулярные выражения.
Вот пример как парсится первая строка:

```py
re.search(r"(?P<t1>\d+:\d+:\d+) (?P<t2>PM|AM) Login successful .*id_session=(?P<sid>\d+)", s).groups()
('10:08:54', 'AM', '2710')
```

Далее изучай.
Чтобы перевести время из строки, смотри модуль datetime функцию strptime